# Ewww plugin jpegtran missing

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using the EWWW plugin in Wordpress. When I optimize the image it shows following lines

*jpegtran* is missing
Image Size: 56.10 KB
jpegtran is missing

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your php.ini

```
disable_functions = "show_source, system, shell_exec, exec"
```

To

```
disable_functions = "show_source, system, shell_exec"
```

Comment: Other solution:

Comment: Other solution: 1 - Rename files in the plugin directory (binaries) according to your operating system, removing the "-name_of_sistem" terminations,
2 - Create a new directory in wp-content/ewww
3 - Copy the files to wp-content/ewww